# What are the different ways of writing output to console in Perl?

Tags: perl, logging, console, printf

I know `print`, `printf`, `die`, `warn` , `say` have different functionality  but all print to console. I am working on a project where I am integrating a logging framework to Perl so i need to know all the functions which print output to console in Perl irrespective of their functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"The console" is a slightly complicated concept. There are actually two filehandles that are, by default, attached to the console. STDOUT is where standard output is written and STDERR is where errors and warnings are written.

Then, of course, those filehandles might not be attached to the console at all. Most operating systems support I/O redirection. STDOUT might be attached to one file and STDERR to another.

And many of these functions allow you to change the filehandle that they write to. For example `print()` takes an optional first argument which is a filehandle.

Then there's `select` which can be used to change the default filehandle which is used by functions like `print()`.

In [perldoc perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) you can find a list of "input and output functions". It's simple enough to go through that list to extract the ones that produce output.

- `die` - writes to STDERR
- `warn` - writes to STDERR
- `print` - writes to STDOUT
- `printf` - writes to STDOUT
- `say` - writes to STDOUT
- `syswrite` - writes to the specified filehandle
- `write` - writes to STDOUT

There are, of course, any number of other modules which can contain new functions which write to various filehandles. For example, [Carp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp) defines the functions, `carp()`, `croak()`, `cluck()` and `confess()` - all of which write to STDERR.

Comment: Thanks @mob. Good to know there are people around to take care of my stupid typos :-/